# PHP / Symfony issue "Unknown record property"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

Below PHP execute code is throwing an error

```
$q = Doctrine::getTable('FormSurvey')->querySurveyByFormRequest($form_request);
$this->results = $q->execute();

public function querySurveyByFormRequest($form_request) {
      $q = Doctrine_Query::create();
      $q->from('FormSurvey FS');
      $q->leftJoin('FS.FormQuestion FQ');
      $q->leftJoin('FQ.Question Q');
      $q->leftJoin('Q.QuestionText QT');
      $q->leftJoin('Q.QuestionSingle QS');
      $q->leftJoin('Q.QuestionMultiple QM');
      $q->leftJoin('QT.Answers AT with AT.form_request_id = ?', $form_request->getId());
      $q->leftJoin('QS.AnswerSingle AS with AS.form_request_id = ?', $form_request->getId());
      $q->leftJoin('QM.AnswerMultiple AM with AM.form_request_id = ?', $form_request->getId());
      $q->where('FS.id = ?', $form_request->getFormSurveyId());
      $q->orderBy('FQ.displayOrder');
      return $q;
    }
```

`$q->getSqlQuery()` Query String working fine in SQLYog but it is throwing below Unknown record property error when we use PHP `execute()`

Error message

```
Unknown record property / related component "<pre>\nalias : FormSurvey\nforeign : id\nlocal : form_survey_id\nclass : FormSurvey\ntype : 0\ntable : Object(FormSurveyTable)\nlocalTable : Object(FormQuestionTable)\nname : \nrefTable : \nonDelete : \nonUpdate : \ndeferred : \ndeferrable : \nconstraint : \nequal : \ncascade : Array\nowningSide : \nrefClassRelationAlias : \nforeignKeyName : \norderBy : \n</pre>" on "FormQuestion", referer: system/applications/referenceforms.html
```

Comment: Wow.  Have not seen Doctrine 1 being used in some time.  All I can really suggest is commenting out all the left joins and then adding them back in one at a time to try and narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the above issue by adding $q->select('FS.*'); before query, so new query is

```
      $q = Doctrine_Query::create();
      $q->select('FS.*');
      $q->from('FormSurvey FS');
      $q->leftJoin('FS.FormQuestion FQ');
      $q->leftJoin('FQ.Question Q');
      $q->leftJoin('Q.QuestionText QT');
      $q->leftJoin('Q.QuestionSingle QS');
      $q->leftJoin('Q.QuestionMultiple QM');
      $q->leftJoin('QT.Answers AT with AT.form_request_id = ?', $form_request->getId());
      $q->leftJoin('QS.AnswerSingle AS with AS.form_request_id = ?', $form_request->getId());
      $q->leftJoin('QM.AnswerMultiple AM with AM.form_request_id = ?', $form_request->getId());
      $q->where('FS.id = ?', $form_request->getFormSurveyId());
      $q->orderBy('FQ.displayOrder');
      return $q;
```